# Using RegularExpressionValidator to set a few fixed characters for my user ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to set up a Product ID for my website and I need my Product ID to be in this format: PIDNNNN (e.g. PID0001, PID0002,.... PID9999 etc). I'm supposed to use RegularExpressionValidator to set the ValidationExpression but it doesn't seems to work.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxProductID" runat="server" MaxLength="7"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtBoxProductID" ErrorMessage="Please enter a Product ID" 
                    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtBoxProductID" 
                    ErrorMessage="Format: PIDNNNN" ForeColor="Red" 
                    ValidationExpression="^[PID]([0-9]{4})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

How can I make the "PID" be fixed characters and the 4 integers to be up to the users to key?

I'm hoping I can code it all in the RegularExpressionValidator and not use Javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need square brackets in this case, just write `^PID([0-9]{4})$` or `^PID(\d{4})$`

Little explanation from wikipedia:

> Bracket expression matches a *single character* that is contained within the brackets. For example, [abc] matches "a", "b", or "c".

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case I would suggest using `Label + Textbox`

In `Label` simply show '`PID`' and in `Textbox`, let users enter the value (with validation).